# Objective-C: Refactoring code - how do I get a pointer to a view instance?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, oop, refactoring, nsview

I am not very experienced with OOP so I wanted to share what I am currently doing and ask for some advice about how I should go about a couple of things.

I am currently working on a simple game that uses a 2d grid. Here is a quick overview of my class structure:

- 'GameBoard'- has an array of the possible cell states for the game, and methods that implement the rules.
- 'GameView' - has the superclass NSView, and is placed in my window as a custom view. This class is intended to read from the game board and draw the contents of the array by mapping the stares to an enumeration of images in its drawRect: method.
- 'GameController' - this is an intermediate class intended to initialise the game board and view, and handle the various UI controls. This class has instance variables of the 'GameBoard' and 'GameView' type.

Originally, I was doing nearly everything in the View class, and had it working fine but it started to get hard really to follow, which was my main reason for wanting to spread my code over a new class.

I have created a method in 'GameController' that initialises a new game, with some user defined parameters (removed in the snippet to save space).

```
-(IBACTION)initialiseGame:(id)sender {
    gameBoard = [[GameBoard alloc] init...];
    gameView = [[GameView alloc] init...];
}
```

What I want to do here is pass the game view a pointer to the game board instance so that I can read it's array to draw the current state of the game, something like:

```
-(void)initWithGameBoard:(GameBoard*)gameBoard;
```

Is this the right way of going about that, or should I be doing this in a different way?

My next problem with moving to the controller class is that I cannot seem to find out how to do is get a pointer to the instance of GameView that I have placed on the window in IB? Would it be better to not place the view on the window in interface builder, and instead place it on the window programatically in the initialiseGame function? If so how would I go about doing that?

I guess one other question would be, should I just scrap this idea and stick to doing everything in the GameDraw class?

Thank you very much for taking your time to read this, this is probably a very simple question to any experienced object-oriented programmer, but I cannot seem to find the answers specifically anywhere.

Comment: First question: Yes, I would normally use a custom initWithSomething init method that itself calls its superclass' Init method.

Comment: Second question. Please be bit more specific or provide much more of your code. Is your GameController a subclass of UIViewController or is it some NSObject that is detached from any View? Plus: Do you use Interface Builder (IB) or do you create all your view objects programmatically?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The GameController class is just a subclass of NSObject at the moment. I used IB to create all of the UI objects, and also to add the GameView to the window. Is it possible to get a pointer to that instance that is on the window, or should I be doing this some other way?

Comment: To get a pointer to the instance you created in IB, you need to create an IBOutlet to it in the controller class.

Comment: @rdelmar exactly what I needed. Just had to #import the class, declare an IBOutlet of the class type, then connect it in IB. From there I am able to access all of the methods I have declared. Got it working fine!

Comment: By the way you can use a forward declaration (`@class GameView;`) in your controller .h file, and import GameView.h in your .m file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more than one way to do make this work, but here's how I would do it:

1. Instantiate the view once in IB. Don't invoke alloc/init yourself.
2. In your view controller, make an outlet for your view and connect it in Interface Builder. That's how your controller will get access to it. Your view controller will need to be the file owner — probably it already is.
3. Design the view to be reusable. Give it a `-setGameBoard:` method for the controller to invoke. Make sure the view can draw something blank when it doesn't have a game board.
4. Write `-initializeGame:` like this:

   ```
   -(IBAction) initialiseGame:(id) sender {
       gameBoard = [[GameBoard alloc] init...];
       [gameView setGameBoard:gameBoard];
   }
   ```

Comment: Note that you can just create a synthesized `gameBoard` property and the appropriate accessor methods will be created for you.

Comment: Sure, though `-setGameBoard` probably also should call `-setNeedsDisplay:` to trigger the view to redraw.

Comment: @noa Thanks for the answer, Got it working now! The solution was remarkably simple - it's just the same as connecting any standard UI object to code. I think what confused me was that I was working with a custom class. I did not realise you could create an IBOutlet for a custom class! I think I understand what goes on when you link something using an IBOutlet now.. It essentially just sets the ivar pointer to reference the instance of the object created by the nib when window was loaded. if my understanding is correct that is! (Im a beginner to OOP, so im not fully clear on it all yet!)

Comment: Sounds like you've got it! Yes, when the nib is loaded it calls `-setWhatever` on all your outlets. After `-init`, before `-awakeFromNib`.